# Bones remember previous keyframes?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, keyframes

I have a bone-animated object. The object has several animations. Bones that do not have keyframes in the second animation perform the moves from the previous animation. Why is this happening? Can this be turned off?
Blender 2.80,
Windows 8.1  [image]

Comment: maybe you've pushed the action (Dope Sheet in Action Editor mode and Push Down button) into the Nonlinear Animation window, open the Nonlinear Animation and see if there's a yellow strip, if this is the case, select and delete

Comment: I didn't push the action (Push Down button).
I use Nonlinear Animation to export an animation, but there is no path to that animation.
The bones move even though there are no keyframes, as in the previously used animation. 
Only after I insert the keyframe do they stop moving. This applies to all bones that do not have keyframes in the animation - they move as if remembering the movements from the previous animation.

Comment: maybe share your file? (armature only) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sometimes I use Append to import, but I don't share files.
I got the feeling there was an option somewhere to remember the bone movements and carry them to the next animation, but now I can't remember where it was. Maybe I accidentally marked something?

Comment: I meant could you please share you file so that we can look into your problem? Share only the armature as we don't need anything else, use pasteall.org/blend

Comment: I send. "Piraiba26xxx.blend"

"000" animation.
The "Tail_02_Upper" bone is moving despite missing keyframes.

Comment: you need to copy paste the URL it will give you once you've uploaded your file

Comment: The only thing I can see in the file is "Tail_02_Upper" **and** "Tail_02_Bottom" making a short wave motion. There are 28 NLA tracks called NlaTrack, NlaTrack.001, NlaTrack.002 etc. up to NlaTrack.027 - if you deactivate them, the movement stops. Or at least if you deactivate all except for NlaTrack.027.

Answer (score 1):

You must have pushed your actions into the NLA somehow, if I open the NLA window here is what I see, all these tracks are playing, if you don't want them to play, disable them.

[image]

Comment: Ok I understand. You have to turn them off after each export.
Thank you for solving the puzzle.
Best regards.
Adam

Comment: It really depends on how and why you're using it, do you need to push them down into the NLA? You can also click on Stash instead of Push Down, it will keep them mute.

Comment: I use "Non Linear Animation" to export only specific animations to UNITY. I have more animations, but I don't want to export all of them.

After deactivating the NLA animation, everything works fine.